# Extracting tabular data from PDF file.The pdf file has text , image as well as tabular data.

Tags: java, python, pdf, data-science, text-extraction

- The pdf file has text as well as tabular data. If not then is there
  any way by which I can understand whether the current page of pdf
  contains tables or not
- I am able to  Extract data from the pdf page but can't confirm whether it is 
  tabular data or verbose(paragraphs) text.

Comment: What have you tryed so far? Any code-examples?